# dotnet pack (.NET 5) creates extra folder for files with no extension when packing staticwebassets

Tags: visual-studio, .net-core, nuget

`dotnet pack` creates extra folder for files with no extension when packing staticwebassets.

**Example:**

if there is a file in wwwroot/myfolder/myfile it packs it as wwwroot/myfolder/myfile/myfile

The package .props however contains the correct original path and structure. This effective prevents publishing projects what have package reference to this package, because during the publish the msbuild task mislead by the .props file list and gives for example:

> Error MSB3025: The source file "C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\5.0.101\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.NET.Publish.targets(237,5): C:\Users\myname.nuget\packages\thepackage\1.0.0\staticwebassets\assets\libs\flot-charts\Makefile" is actually a directory. The "Copy" task does not support copying directories.

Can anyone suggest a workaround (besides of deleting or renaming the files)?

Comment: Any update about this issue?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that there is something wrong with Copy Task from your `<packages_id>.props` file,

**Copy** task should work with files rather than a folder, so you should use this:

```
    <ItemGroup>
           <File Include="$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)xxx\staticwebassets\assets\libs\flot-charts\Makefile\*.*"></File>
    </ItemGroup>
    
<Target Name="xxx" AfterTargets="xxx">
     <Copy SourceFiles="@(File)" DestinationFolder="xxx"></Copy>

</Target>
```

Comment: Perry the .props file is auto generated, if there is an error in it, that is the issue itself. If have no artifacts in my projects related to how to create packages, only the csproj files. The whole process uses all defaults,  and the pure dotnet pack command

Comment: Did you use a razor class library project? Not sure that what your project type is and your detailed situation. You should provide more steps about your situation to help us troubleshoot the issue. Maybe you could share a small sample with github. Besides, you should set `Build Action` of the files under `wwwroot` folder from your project to `Content`.